# How to construct the input files to obtain the structural measurements using Quntum Espresso?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, optical-properties

I'm working with a SiPOCa structure and I've already done the SCF, NSCF, DOS, BANDS, CHARGE DENSITY, FTIR and RAMAN calculations. Now I would like to calculate the structural measurements of this structure using DFT and Quantum Espresso. Can anyone explain to me how I create the input files to perform these new calculations? Or if anyone can point me to some study material so I can learn

Comment: +1 by my edit was made because questions need to be posted one at a time.